# Programmatically creating app without using storyboards: simulator shows me a black screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just recently adopted programming without storyboards and I am slightly confused. My code is not working as expected. It is telling me that there is some warning in my main.storyboard file though I don't even intend to use that file. Here is my initialisation code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I set this as the initial view controller and the error went off... But the simulator still shows me a black screen.

Why is it showing me this when I don't even want to use the main.storyboard file?

Update:

I have tried almost all of your answers...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you delete the reference to the Main storyboard in your project's settings? See this screenshot: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/2768f8ac3f92a5d9778e966607982994304d95c3/cbba6/images/no-storyboard-delete-reference.png

Comment: Ohh... no... Thanks! I'll try that!

Comment: What do I change it to?

Comment: I can only see main.storyboard and launch screen

Comment: It was already "Main" when I created the project

Comment: just leave it empty

Comment: I already have and im still getting white screen

Comment: See my edited question

Comment: just for sanity check, did you do a clean folder/clean build (cmd + shift + k, cmd+k)

Comment: Yes. I have Joshua!

Comment: Though I am really going insane!!1

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Hey Frankenstein, no.... but I will send you a YouTube link and hopefully you can let me know what I'm doing wrong! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kl-3jAeoWXI

Comment: Please post copy/pasted versions of your code and errors, not images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete the `Main.storyboard` file from your project. In the project navigator, select the target and clear Main interface field under Deployment info.

Next, edit Info.plist file and remove the value for key 'Main storyboard file base name'. Set it to empty string.

[image]

If you are using Xcode 11 or higher, on creating a new Single View App, Xcode will create the `SceneDelegate.swift` file. It will also make some entries to the Info.plist file. To cleanup these storyboard entires, click Application Scene Manifest —> Scene Configuration —> Application Session Role —> Item 0 (Default Configuration) to expand it, click the minus(-) button at the end of the Storyboard Name item to remove it. The value `Main` for this key implies that the `SceneDelegate.swift` file will use the `Main.storyboard` file, but it is already removed.

[image]

If you run the app, the project will successfully build and install, but you will only see an empty screen as you have now removed the `window` of your application.

In `AppDelegate.swift`, add the following code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window!.rootViewController = MapController()
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Also, remember to `return true` from this method.

If your app uses the `SceneDelegate.swift` file, modify this file instead.  Add the following code to `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` method:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
window?.rootViewController = MapController()
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

On running the app now, you will see a white screen as that is the background color you have set to the MapController.

Comment: Trying it :) I hope this works

Comment: Hey sats, it built successfully but then my app crashed...

Comment: Template[12391:789321] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/tejas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C2C4365C-F34C-4E5B-AFE2-068D8DEBA387/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1A1DAF2F-8601-4C98-BECE-63172A7AB154/Map Template.app> (loaded)'

Comment: This was the error... I deleted the main.storyboard file and my interface builder column was completely empty

Comment: Edit Info.plist file and remove the value for key 'Main storyboard file base name'. Set it to empty string.

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of where that is in the info.plist file?? I'm having trouble finding it!

Comment: I have modified the answer.

Comment: Hey sats, such a column doesn't even exist in my info.plist file... It just has a launch screen interface file base name

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? Also, can you please share your Info.plist file?

Comment: Yup, just updated my question, you can see my info.plist file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214139/discussion-between-tejas-and-sats).

Comment: I have modified the answer . Please check.

Comment: Hey sats, the error is gone, but still the view's background colour is not changing

Comment: I know that the view is loading up due to the fact that I added a print statement for the view did load but the color of the view is not changing

Comment: I tried the same code on my machine and it is working fine - the color changes are applied. If you are having difficulties changing the color of the view controller programmatically, please ask a new question for the same as additional details will be required to help you out.

Comment: I have created a YouTube video showing this problem... Will send you the link soon

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kl-3jAeoWXI

Comment: Here is what I am doing... let me know what im doing wrong please!! Thanks!

Comment: I have modified the answer with SceneDelegate.swift. Please check.